# How can I use PowerShell to translate a full name to samaccountname without middle initial?

Tags: powershell

What I have now is a PS script that parses through a text file.
The text file is structured like this:

```
John Smith
Anna Jones
John Brown
```

The problem is, the Display Name in AD is something like this:

```
John C. Smith
Anna G. Jones
John A. Brown
```

And I don't know the middle initials. I've pasted the script I have. It will give me the correct samaccountname if I include the middle initial in the text file. But again, I don't know the middle initials of all these users. Is there a way to get the samaccountname if I don't know the middle initial? Maybe pass a wildcard into the query?

```
$users = Get-Content C:\Temp\UserList.txt

foreach ($user in $users){
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$user'" | Select-Object samaccountname
}
```

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ARTools/2016.4.21/Content/Public%5CSearch-ADAccountByName.ps1).

Answer (score 1):

something like this may work

```
$users = Get-Content C:\Temp\UserList.txt

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $split = $user.split()
    $first = $split[0]
    $last = $split[-1]
    Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$first*$last'" | Select-Object samaccountname
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach. I'll just point out that you might see better performance by matching against `givenname` for first name and `sn` for surname, with the caveat that this won't work if different first names are used (such as nicknames). `Get-ADUser -Filter {(givenname -eq $first) -and (sn -eq $last)}`

Comment: That certainly did the job. Thanks!